# How to avoid typos in django's permission strings

Tags: django, django-permissions

According to the docs custom permissions can be created and used like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
        )
```

Using the permission:

```
user.has_perm('app.view_task')
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

If there is a typo in the permission string. For example: I use `user.has_perm('app.view_tasks')`, then this typo won't be noticed.

## Goal 1

I would like to get an exception or warning if not existing permissions get used.

## Goal 2

To avoid typos in the first place, I would like to have constants: `user.PERM_APP_VIEW_TASKS` or something like this.

Comment: So what is actual question? For goal 1 you can change `has_perm` method on user so it will check if permission exist in db with `Permission.objects.get(...)` and for goal 2 you can create class variables

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev the question is "how to solve this in the most pythonic way?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Goal 1

Override the `has_perm` method of the `ModelBackend` class, from my `backends.py` file:

```
import logging
from difflib import get_close_matches
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class ModelBackendHelper(ModelBackend):
    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        if not user_obj.is_active:
            return False
        else:
            obj_perms = self.get_all_permissions(user_obj, obj)
            allowed = perm in obj_perms

            if not allowed:
                if settings.DEBUG:
                    similar = get_close_matches(perm, obj_perms)

                    if similar:
                        logging.warn("{0} not found, but is similar to: {1}".format(perm, ','.join(similar)))

            return allowed
```

How it works:

Same logic of `has_perm` but if `settings.DEBUG` is `True` and similar versions of `perm` are found then output a warning log message of level `WARN`:

```
WARNING:root:myapp.view_tasks not found, but is similar to: myapp.view_task
```

Change the value of `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['myapp.backends.ModelBackendHelper']
```

This can be used both in production and development environments but personally I wouldn't include this in a production site, I hope that when everything goes to production permissions are consolidated.

### Goal 2

Permissions belong to models and to keep this DRY I'm reusing the permissions defined in `Meta`:

```
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
        )


def _get_perm(model, perm):
    for p in model._meta.permissions:
        if p[0] == perm:
            return p[0]
    err = "Permission '{0}' not found in model {1}".format(perm, model)
    raise Exception(err)


def format_perm(perm):
    return '{0}.{1}'.format(__package__, perm)


def get_perm(model, type):
    return format_perm(_get_perm(model, type))


PERM_APP_VIEW_TASK = get_perm(Task, "view_task")
```

Permissions can be accessed with `get_perm` or with a shortcut `PERM_APP_VIEW_TASK`:

```
models.PERM_APP_VIEW_TASK
# or
get_perm(Task, "view_task")
# or
format_perm(_get_perm(Task, "view_task"))
```

In case of searching for a missing permission `get_perm` will raise an `Exception`:

```
PERM_APP_VIEW_TASK = get_perm(Task, "add_task")
```

Message:

```
Exception: Permission 'add_task' not found in model <class 'myapp.models.Task'>
```

Comment: Doesn't this show a warning in all cases when a user doesn't have a permission, even if the permission is correctly spelled?

Comment: How does this work if you are using multiple `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, for example, with django-allauth? Wouldn't you have override allauths implementation too?

Answer (score 0):

## Goal 1

Create a custom decorator:

## Warning! untested code!!!!!

```
@permission_required
def assert_permission(permission):
    def real_decorator(original_function):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            permission_object = Permission.objects.filter(codename=permission)
            if not permission_object.exists():
                raise ValueError("This permission does not exist!")
            original_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

## Goal 2

Add constants to your model classes and refer to those whenever asking for specific permissions.
example:

```
class Task(models.Model):
MY_PERMISSION_CONSTANT = 'app.view_task'
...
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        (MY_PERMISSION_CONSTANT, "Can see available tasks"),
    )

@permission_required(Task.MY_PERMISSION_CONSTANT)
def some_view(request):
  pass
```

Comment: Are you sure that Goal1 cannot be achieved? For me all permissions in the db are valid. Every string which does not correspond to a db row is invalid.

Comment: @guettli haven't been able to test this, but i assume that should work, or at least get you in the right direction, if something doesn't work and you fix it, please edit this answer ;)